# Why would we need any type wirings other than those for queries?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

In GraphQL Java implementation's [document](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v16/schema/), type wiring is done as below, which contains one for the `human` query and one for the `friends` field of the `Human` type as highlighted.

[image]

I am wondering what is the use of the latter, the one for the `friends` field of the `Human` type.

I think we already return the a whole `Human` object, including the `friends` field, in the former type wiring using the `StarWarsData.getHumanDataFetcher()`, then why we need the latter?

Thanks!

The schema is as below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `friends`field is of type `Character[]`. When you return a certain type, fields that aren't of a built-in scalar type (such as `String`, which is built-in, vs. `Character` which isn't) require their own fetcher in order to be retrieved. [You can, however, define a DTO that models the `Human` type and the smart `graphql.schema.PropertyDataFetcher` provided by graphql-java should retrieve the fields of your POJO, since it knows how to follow POJO patterns based on the field name](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/data-fetching/).

Comment: But, cannot I just return an entire `Human` object including `friends` using `StarWarsData.getHumanDataFetcher()`?

Comment: A DataFetcher provides the data for a field. Therefore, every field definition should have a DataFetcher. If a field doesn't have a specific DataFetcher, a PropertyDataFetcher is used instead. `Human` uses the built-in fetchers for `ID`, `name` and `homePlanet` as they are of built-in scalar types, but would need specific fetchers for `friends` because `Character` is not one such built-in type.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answer, but I think it is not actually on the point. If `StarWarsData.getHumanDataFetcher()` returns a DTO containing a field named `friends`, the default `PropertyDataFetcher` should be able to fetch it, therefore the reason for a specific DataFetch should be something else.

Comment: PropertyDataFetcher is only used if there is no specific DataFetcher, as I said in my previous comment. I don't think we can know the reason for having a specific DataFetcher for `friends` in this case without knowing the implementation details (perhaps `Human` does not have a DTO that correctly models the type and thus a PropertyDataFetcher would not work?). Might be a matter of developer preference, might be a matter of a specific need that the custom DataFetcher covers (but we're not told about it), might just be a style choice for the sake of the example.

Comment: I think what I would like to learn is the reasoning of behind the fields. Aka, why some implementations choose to not include a `friends` field in the DTO and to create a separate Datafetcher? I mean, if DTOs cover every fields, we only Datafetchers for queries and mutations, but not any fields, isn't it cleaner?

Comment: The only benefit I can think of is that, if we have a separate Datafetcher for a field, then when this field is not queried, this Datafetcher will not be called, therefore we save some calculation capacity. If we only have one Datafetcher for all fields as a whole, then all fields will be calculated, no matter if they are wanted or not. Hope that makes sense. But, are there any other reasons?

Comment: None that come to mind right now, but yes, the one you thought of is a pretty good reason. I was gonna mention it, but you're faster with your comments :P